# why $K_1 \cap K_{\alpha_1} \cap ...\cap K_{\alpha_n}=\emptyset$ give contradiction?

Tags: real-analysis

I have some confusion in **Baby Rudin** book

My doubt is given below marked in red line and red circle
[image]

**My attempt** : Here we have already assume  that no point
of $K_1$ belongs to every $ K_{\alpha} $ that mean it implies already $K_1 \cap K_{\alpha_1} \cap ...\cap K_{\alpha_n}=\emptyset$

**My doubts**:  why  $K_1 \cap K_{\alpha_1} \cap ...\cap K_{\alpha_n}=\emptyset$ give contradiction ?

**Edit**:here $K_1$ is compact  and open cover are  $G_\alpha$ and so $K_1 \cap G_\alpha^c = \emptyset$ this implies  again $K_1 \cap K_\alpha=\emptyset$  ......why  its  contradicts?

Comment: You assume that any finite intersection of such terms is non-empty. Read the statement of the theorem again.

Comment: i read  the statement @Randall ya  u r right  but  here $K_1$ is compact  and open cover are  $G_\alpha$ and so $K_1 \cap G_\alpha^c = \emptyset$ this implies  again $K_1 \cap K_\alpha=\emptyset$  ......why  its  contradicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key of the theorem is to get that precise contradiction, since you were assuming every finite subcollection of the compact sets $\{K_\alpha\}$ had nonempty intersection.

The way to get the contradiction is by assuming we don't have the result (reductio ad absurdum). Assuming that we don't have the result is assuming $\bigcap K_\alpha=\emptyset$.

If you fix one compact set $K_1$ then for every point $x\in K_1$ there is some $\alpha_x$ such that $x\notin K_{\alpha_x}$, since otherwise we would have $x\in K_\alpha\;\forall \alpha$, but that would mean $x\in\bigcap K_\alpha$, and we were assuming the contrary.

Then for every $x\in K_1$ there is some $\alpha_x$ such that $x\in G_{\alpha_x}:=K_{\alpha_x}^\mathsf c$. Every $G_\alpha$ is open, since compact subsets are closed in metric spaces. In consequence:

$\forall x\in K_1\;x\in G_{\alpha_x}\Rightarrow K_1\subset\bigcup_\limits{x\in K_1}G_{\alpha_x}$, so $\{G_{\alpha_x}\}_{x\in K_1}$ is an open cover of $K_1$. Since $K_1$ is compact, we must have a finite subcover $K_1\subset G_{\alpha_{x_1}}\cup\cdots\cup G_{\alpha_{x_n}}$.

Now, remember that $G_\alpha:= K_\alpha^\mathsf c$, so we actually have $K_1\subset K_{\alpha_{x_1}}^\mathsf c\cup\cdots\cup K_{\alpha_{x_n}}^\mathsf c$, which means

$K_{\alpha_{x_1}}\cap\cdots\cap K_{\alpha_{x_n}}=\big(K_{\alpha_{x_1}}^\mathsf c\cup\cdots\cup K_{\alpha_{x_n}}^\mathsf c\big)^\mathsf c\subset K_1^c$, which implies

$K_{\alpha_{x_1}}\cap\cdots\cap K_{\alpha_{x_n}}\cap K_1=\emptyset$

But $\{K_{\alpha_{x_1}},\cdots, K_{\alpha_{x_n}},K_1\}$ is a finite subcollection of the compact sets $\{K_\alpha\}$, so it should have nonempty intersection by hypothesis. We got our contradiction!

This must means that the thing we assumed is false, so the opposite is true: We have that $\bigcap K_\alpha\neq\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
K_1\subseteq X\setminus(K_{\alpha_1}\cap K_{\alpha_2}\cap\dots\cap K_{\alpha_n})
$$
Now it's a general feature of sets that, if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $C$, then $A\subseteq C\setminus B$ implies $A\cap B=\emptyset$, because if $a\in A$, then $a\in X\setminus B$ and therefore $a\notin B$.

The assumption on the family $(K_\alpha)$ is that the intersection of any finite set of members of the family is not empty, but $K_1,K_{\alpha_1},\dots,K_{\alpha_n}$ *is* a finite set of members of the family.

---

Maybe it is useful to see a different version of the proof. Fix a member $K$ of the family and the family of subsets of $K$ defined by $C_\alpha=K\cap K_\alpha$.

<sup>Here we're assuming that the given family is not empty, which also Rudin does (without mentioning it explicitly).</sup>

The family $(C_\alpha)$ is a family of closed subsets of $K$ (because in a metric space compact sets are closed) and $K$ is compact. If $\bigcap_{\alpha}C_\alpha=\emptyset$, then $(U_\alpha)$, where $U_\alpha=K\setminus C_\alpha$, is an open cover of $K$ and so it has a finite subcover:
$$
U_{\alpha_1}\cup U_{\alpha_2}\cup\dots U_{\alpha_n}=K
$$
that becomes
$$
C_{\alpha_1}\cap C_{\alpha_2}\cap\dots \cap C_{\alpha_n}=\emptyset
$$
But this means that
$$
(K\cap K_{\alpha_1})\cap (K\cap K_{\alpha_2})\cap\dots \cap (K\cap K_{\alpha_n})=\emptyset
$$
and therefore
$$
K\cap K_{\alpha_1}\cap K_{\alpha_2}\cap\dots \cap K_{\alpha_n}=\emptyset
$$
against the assumption.